# Is it safe to delete the recovery partition of Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I have a convertible laptop, Asus Transformer T200TA, which came with Windows 8.1 preinstalled (unfortunately)

I'd like to try setting up Ubuntu there but all the space is taken by the Windows stuff.

There's a 8G recovery partition which contains whole lot of weird files which previously were on USB drives I booted from.

Is it safe to remove the recovery partition? Does it serve any reasonable purpose if I have already done a backup with Clonezilla?

Comment: It is a Windows recovery partition.  So if you are going to install Ubuntu you really don't need it.

Comment: If you have everything securely backed up, it doesn't matter what you delete. The recovery partition returns your PC to its delivered state, useful if you want to sell. Otherwise, a Windows install disc gives a lot more flexibility about what you overwrite. In either case you will need the manufacturer's OEM partition or its contents, which has the drivers for all your specific hardware (unless you want to do a lot of down-loading). That said, I wouldn't have thought 8GB worth recovering. I found that shrinking Windows C: to ~100GB released plenty of space for Ubuntu.

Comment: 8G is worth recovering when you have 32G total :)